# Not passing test with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to test if my function is going to throw an error but it's not working. I took a look on another questions here and the solution should be to wrap the function that throws the error inside a callback function inside expect.

My function look something like this

```
function myFunc (str) {

  if (typeof str !== "string") {
    throw Error("Enter a string")
    }

return str
}
```

And my test looks something like this

```
test("should get a string as an input", () => {
    expect(() => {
        myFunc(42354);
    }).toThrow(Error);
});
```

When I run this test I always encounter the error thrown by my function before passing the test. How can I improve this?

Comment: What is not working there?

Comment: I realized that the test wasn't working because I was running the function in the file with the function and when running the tests was getting the error from there. Now I removed and it works fine. Thanks for your help.